# Connecting to an online database in c#

Tags: c#

So I'm a developer and we're running a project. I'm using HeidiSQL to connect to our DB, which uses TCP/IP over port 3306 with
my username and password.

I'm developing something in c# for the server and I want to connect to the database which is hosted on the IP(I'm connecting
to the IP via HeidiSQL normally btw, it works fine).

And when I try it in c#,

```
string connectionstring = "Data Source=ourIP,3306;Initial Catalog=auth, User ID=myusernameforserv, Password=mypasswordforserv";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

and I get an error saying that it can't connect to the database. First it was saying that the database doesn't exist or that
I don't have access to it, now it gives me the error "Error state:18".

I'm not using any NuGET's on my code, just the using system.sql.dataclient.

Comment: Which database is it? SqlConnection is for SQLServer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using semi-colons after each thing, just as you have after the data source.

```
string connectionstring = "Data Source=ourIP,3306;Initial Catalog=auth;User ID=myusernameforserv;Password=mypasswordforserv";
```

Comment: sorry I figured it out, the thing is I had to use MYSQL instead of SQL